# How can I change hue of a vector image that has many colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, tiles

How can I change color of this vector in Illustrator? Each triangle is different. I want it to be in other color tones like brown, grey etc.

[image: a image consisting of many triangles, each a different shade of purple]

Answer (score 29):

- Select all
- Choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork`
- Click the **Edit** tab at the top
- Click the **Link colors** icon in the middle of the window
- Move the color wheel indicators or....
- Set the sliders to **Global Adjust** and then adjust the sliders

[image: recolor]

Comment: Scott, the first time I recolored everything worked as expected. The second time however, Illustrator is insisting on recoloring what has already been recolored - shifting the color further to an undesired hue. I want Illustrator to only recolor colors that are in my *current selection*. What should I do differently? Thanks.

Comment: Using the Recolor artwork is **not** a "live" effect. Once applied, the colors are different. There's no longer any reference to the colors you originally started with.

Comment: That's what I was expecting. The problem is that the colors Illustrator wants to change are not the ones I've selected. I've got objects with only blues selected and it's trying to change the reds of some other (unselected) object. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I just figured it out! The blue objects were linked to an original red object. I had to click the "Break Link" button and then I was allowed to replace their blue colors.